# How does the Multiview control handle its Viewstate?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-2.0

Does the Multiview control contain the viewstate information for each of its views regardless of whether or not the view is currently visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does, all the views are still there, just the inactive ones are hidden/disabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview_properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, yes.  It would be quite simple to confirm using a ViewState Decoder (google it, there are tools available from Fritz Onion or as FireFox plugins).

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that the viewstate contains information for each of a Multiview's views/controls. Otherwise, there's no way it would be able to keep track of the state of the controls in each view- unless you were using some sort of custom state management.